# Is there a way to start gdb up in single-key mode?

Tags: gdb

When I start up gdb, the first thing I do is hit C-x, s to go into single-key mode. A startup option would be nice to have, or a .gdbinit command.

Comment: I did check the man page, the manual, and the startup options before posting the question, perhaps I should have clarified it in the body. There are often other, indirect ways of solving a user preference problem, which is why I asked. May I ask why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't one.

Your best bet is to file a bug in the gdb bugzilla.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to check it out carefully on GDB Manual, if there is no such command, you can just modify GDB source code to do it, or write a command-line-file-for-gdb, and use -x option to start gdb.

Comment: You just need to add a command of `C-x` right after the command of `gdb`, not that hard, trust me, I've done such thing a lot.